# Sudo throwing a "Bad item passed to pam_*_item()" error

Tags: ubuntu, sudo, locale

I was trying to install ROS 2 on my Ubuntu and I ran the following cell:

```
locale  # check for UTF-8

sudo apt update && sudo apt install locales
sudo locale-gen en_US en_US.UTF-8
sudo update-locale LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Now when I try to do a simple `sudo apt update`, I get this:

```
sudo: pam_open_session: Bad item passed to pam_*_item()
sudo: policy plugin failed session initialization
```

This is my /etc/default/locale:

```
#  File generated by update-locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE="en_CA:en"
=
```

Comment: Remove the line with just an equals sign (`=`) from `/etc/default/locale`. You'll need to get root permissions to do this; `su` if you have it, or else with a rescue boot

Comment: I can't use sudo so how can I remove it?

Comment: Like I suggested, `su` if you have it, or else with a rescue boot.

Comment: What is rescue boot?

Comment: And how can I access su without sudo?

Comment: `su` doesn't need `sudo`. Just use `su` and enter the _root_ password. If you didn't set one then you'll need to use a rescue boot